# Which browser is better for work with javascript? Any other tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

It's quite difficult to find id's in page. F.e. it's much easier to work with picture and then   get id from popup. I use Chrome but feel it can be much better and easier. My question is.

Which browser is better for work  with javascript? Any other tools?

Comment: What's difficult about right-click / inspect element? I think Chrome is about as easy as it gets.

Comment: I have no idea what are you asking us about. Care to clarify?

Comment: That's a quite subjective question that is likely not going to get very good answers....

Comment: Your question is nearly incomprehensible. What are you trying to do? Find ID's in page? What page, your page? What is so hard about finding an ID? How do you work with pictures instead of ID's?

Comment: @Anton please explain more what exactly you want to ask..you question not clear..normally all major browsers(except IE in some area) are good enough to run your javaScript code

Comment: I love the built-in dev tools that chrome/webkit provide. I guess you just need to learn how to use it :) http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html

Comment: Are there any master classes about working with js, jquery in browsers I haven't found any informative video lessons or tutorials. I'm new to jQuery but I see that it's much more difficult to navigate and to read scripts then code.

Comment: and no, there's no Siri kind of tool :)

Comment: Probably my question is: "Can I make life easier when I add js to pages?" Because everyone knows that coding is not for computers but for people who will read it. And page becomes less readable and less understandable.

Comment: I still dont really understand what youre asking. You mean, how can you better learn to decode jquery? I personally li,e working in jsfiddle.com most of the time because of jslint, it tells you any errors you have in your js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All major modern browsers are good for javascript developent and debugging.

- Chrome has it's DevTools built-in http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/chrome/devtools/
- Firefox has Firebug http://getfirebug.com/
- Internet Explorer (starting with 8) has it's developer tools as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa740478

All these tools provide the same (or very close) set of utilities to debug/inspect your code

They all vary on the javascript engines and have their pros and cons, but jQuery is here to help to remediate these discrepancies to provide you with unified platform that works the same on all browsers.

Comment: seriously adding ie to that list? Ie should never be pointed to as good.

Comment: Yes, seriously. IE8 is making more and more progress on getting their browser out of the "dark side". I know there are people that just say "Microsoft is evil, and their software is crap". That just is ridiculous. I say, all modern browsers are trying to become more and more compliant with web standards, try to be faster, introduce hardware acceleration and decent utilities that help developers. You have your predjudices, but face it IE9 is a good (and a whole a lot better than IE7/8) and is moving in the right direction. Hey, btw - just listen :) http://goo.gl/9wGyx

Answer (score 0):

As per me, Chrome and Firefox are better for java script. This is because easy nonavailability of debugging tools and development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 8.0 and later, apparently, 'cuz [scratchpad](http://blog.mozilla.com/devtools/2011/08/15/introducing-scratchpad/) is so convenient when you need to write some code.
But scratchpad is yet to be improved since it still lacks many features of a text-editor.

If anyone finds out an equivalent tool on Google Chrome, pls let me know.